# Process Buillder field updates on child record trigger multiple flow interviews for PB on parent record

Tags: process-builder, roll-up-summary

I came across this "issue" yesterday which I cant figure out if it's an expected behavior or something is wrong.

- I have 3-4 roll-up summary fields on the Order Object summarizing amounts of the OrderItems belonging to an order (e.g. total price, total tax etc..).
- I also have a Process Builder on Order Item which has in total 4 field update actions.

I noticed that when the OrderItem is inserted and the 4 field updates are happening, 4 interviews of the Process Builder on ORDER are launched....

I verified that the number of interviews launched for the Order PB is equal to the number of update actions in my OrderItem PB by deleting/adding field update actions...

This doesnt happen if I do the field updates using good old workflow rules.. Is this supposed to work this way that every single field update causes the parent record to be updated and go through the PB flow?

This doesn't seem to be true for the triggers i.e. the order trigger executes only once.

*Note: There is no recursive update used in any of the PBs.*

**3009E000000A2F5** --> This is the PB on the order

```
16:42:43.509 (9329660406)|DML_BEGIN|[356]|Op:Upsert|Type:OrderItem|Rows:1
16:42:43.509 (9342169283)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Flow:OrderItem
16:42:43.509 (9363194920)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Flow:OrderItem
16:42:43.509 (9389157744)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q9E000000GXHu
16:42:44.513 (9664925030)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CCH_OrderItemTrigger on OrderItem trigger event BeforeInsert|__sfdc_trigger/CCH_OrderItemTrigger
16:42:44.513 (9829174139)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q9E000000GXHu
16:42:44.513 (9834030928)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CCH_OrderItemTrigger on OrderItem trigger event AfterInsert|__sfdc_trigger/CCH_OrderItemTrigger
16:42:44.513 (9835271653)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:OrderItem
16:42:44.958 (9958721832)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D9E0000008pox|3009E000000A2Mz|3019E000000baRH
16:42:45.49 (10049041270)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.62 (10062936985)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D9E0000008pox|3009E000000A2F5|3019E000000h6ec
16:42:45.49 (10309088020)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.372 (10372567670)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.398 (10398286727)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D9E0000008pox|3009E000000A2F5|3019E000000h6ec
16:42:45.372 (10645715042)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.727 (10727805284)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.743 (10743013663)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D9E0000008pox|3009E000000A2F5|3019E000000h6ec
16:42:45.727 (10959414792)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.961 (10961943640)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:OrderItem
16:42:45.961 (10962793402)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.979 (10979083062)|FLOW_CREATE_INTERVIEW_BEGIN|00D9E0000008pox|3009E000000A2F5|3019E000000h6ec
16:42:45.961 (11219057752)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Workflow:Order
16:42:45.961 (11245185874)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q9E000000GWrD
16:42:45.961 (11255060165)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CCH_OrderTrigger on Order trigger event BeforeUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/CCH_OrderTrigger
16:42:45.961 (11302642514)|CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01q9E000000GWrD
16:42:45.961 (11307257895)|CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|CCH_OrderTrigger on Order trigger event AfterUpdate|__sfdc_trigger/CCH_OrderTrigger
16:42:45.961 (11312240646)|DML_END|[356]
```

Comment: Are the PB Field Updates in the same Action Group or in different action groups? (i.e. attached to different decision blocks)

Comment: @cropredy they are in the same action group (same decision block)

Comment: Please show a screen shot of all the actions in the PB